# Error: No countries or regions have been selected for this track

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play

I get this error while releasing my app to Play Store: Error

No countries or regions have been selected for this track. Add at least one country or region to roll out this release.

[image]

Comment: Can you please provide more detail, such as the part where you select the countries? A screenshot of that would be helpful

Answer (score 88, accepted):

Go to: Production > Countries / Regions

Then add the countries you want.

[image]